# Programação inciante

Tags: python

Faça um programa que mostre na tela uma pergunta de múltipla escolha, e que, a partir da resposta do usuário, mostre na tela se ele acertou ou não.

Não conseguir desenvolver essa pergunta, meu código ficou assim:

```py
print("Exercício 02: ")
print("O maior rio em extensão territorial é o rio Nilo ?")

resposta = str(input("Se for verdadeiro escrava sim"))

if resposta != sim:
    print("você acertou!")
else:
    print('Você errou!')
```

Mas o programa não consegue compilar

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seu programa não está executando porque na sua condicional você está comparando resposta com `sim`, onde sim deveria ser uma string utilizando aspas.

Corrigido

```py
print("Exercício 02: ")
print("O maior rio em extensão territorial é o rio Nilo ?")

resposta = str(input("Se for verdadeiro escrava sim"))

if resposta != "sim":
    print("você acertou!")
else:
    print("Você errou!")
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.